# How to make table header fixed when scrolling and table scroll goes background

Tags: css, html-table, fixed-header-tables

I am using table (angular-4-data-table) which displays the rows. I wanted to have a vertical scrollbar with header fixed. I tried to add `style= position: fixed;` to the
`<thead>` section. I can see the fixed header, but when I scroll through, the table data section was moving on top of the header.

```
 <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered data-table">
            <thead style= position: fixed;>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any style that I can apply on tbody so that when scroll happens, it hides beneath the header.

Answer (score 0):

`tbody` tag is relative so it will just operate as every other element in the page.
You should work only on the "special" element (`thead`) in order to let the browser works with the highest number of common element possible.

Have you tried giving `z-index:999;` as thead style?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I remember how to do that.

Inside each `<th>` insert a `<div>` with the content of the column header, than using CSS you must set the div position absolute over the table and the th with 0 height.
Plus, you must give to a `<div>` containing the table a top-padding to leave the space for the fake `<th>`
It's not a nice code, but it works without JS.

```
<style>
    .container { padding-top: 50px; }
    .inner { height: 100px; overflow-y: auto; }
    .t { width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; }
    .t thead th { height: 0 !important; }
    .t thead th > div {
        position: absolute;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        top: 0;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <table class="t">
            <thead><tr>
                <th><div>col 1</div></th>
                <th><div>col 2</div></th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>b</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```